# Errors when compiling Boost with Clang

Tags: c++, boost, clang, c++builder

I'm trying to use boost in an application in C++ Builder (embarcadero), and I'm getting some very weird errors when including boost/filesystem.hpp and compiling with Clang, and I just can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

The errors look like this:

```
[CLANG Error] logical_op.hpp(145): unknown type name 'or__rebind'
[CLANG Error] if.hpp(72): unknown type name 'if__rebind'
[CLANG Error] eval_if.hpp(43): unknown type name 'eval_if_rebind'
[CLANG Error] identity.hpp(28): unknown type name 'identity_rebind'
[CLANG Error] identity.hpp(37): unknown type name 'make_identity_rebind'
[CLANG Error] not.hpp(44): unknown type name 'not__rebind'
```

All these errors occur when the function `BOOST_MPL_AUX_LAMBDA_SUPPORT()` is used, and they only seem to occur when using Clang. The code compiles fine with Borlands own compiler.

It happens even if it's a completely new project, and the only line I've added is `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`.

Edit: I have just tried including `<boost/thread.hpp>` instead, and here is a snip of the errors thrown:

```
[CLANG Error] greg_month.hpp(62): type 'greg_month_rep' (aka 'constrained_value<greg_month_policies>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'boost::gregorian::greg_month'
[CLANG Error] greg_month.hpp(64): type 'greg_month_rep' (aka 'constrained_value<greg_month_policies>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'boost::gregorian::greg_month'
[CLANG Error] greg_month.hpp(68): use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
[CLANG Error] greg_month.hpp(69): use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
```

Kindly tell me if I need to include more information.

Is there any compiler flags I need to set, or something else I could've missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post [the code illustrating the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It happens even when I just create an empty project and include boost/filesystem.hpp, though fx boost/thread/once.hpp works fine.

Comment: Post the clang command line that your IDE is generating.

Comment: Which version of boost and which version of C++Builder are you using? There are so many macro expansions in boost that depend on matching versions correctly, that it's easy to get them out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change $CG_BOOST_ROOT to $CG_64_BOOST_ROOT for using BCC32C (CLANG) to get the shipped BOOST 1.55 instead of 1.39:

read here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Boost